# Returning a value back to the same livewire component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to send a property, `maxId` back with my user data. This property is the id of the last row received from the database (cursor-based pagination). I do this like so:

```
public $maxId = 0;

public function loadMore()
{
    //?
}

public function render()
{
    $data = User::where('id', '>', $maxId)->limit(10)->get();
    $data->maxId = $data->last()->id;

    return view('livewire.users', ['users' => $data]);
}
```

But how can I return (or retain the data on the server) of `maxId` so I know where to start collecting my data from next time.

Please note I do not wish to implement standard laravel pagination.

Comment: You should also order by the ID. But I'm not sure I understand the problem, could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: How can I pass through a value to a view, then pass that value back to the component on the server?

Comment: You can use methods like `$set` or emit events, or call methods with given arguments - but you shouldn't need to, since livewire can manage the state for you. You can just call the method to load more, and handle it all there?